# Help with product rule, derivatives, in conjunction with quotient rule

Tags: calculus

[image]

The above equations tell how to use the quotient rule to apply the below equation to negative values of n for $x^n$.

[image]

What I do not understand lies in the first set of equations in the second line specifically at $$-mx^{-m-1}$$

How does dividing $-mx^{m-1}$ by $x^{2m}$ equal $-mx^{-m-1}$?

Comment: Power laws: $x^a/x^b=x^{a-b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\frac{-mx^{m-1}}{x^{2m}}=-mx^{m-1}*x^{-2m}=-mx^{m-1-2m}=-mx^{m-2m-1}=-mx^{-m-1}$